# Local and global costmap issues

Tags: navigation, rviz, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I got an issue with the configuration of the local and global costmaps.
I end up with this situation:

[image: image description]

For RVIZ, there is no trouble with my costmaps.

Here are my config files:

local_costmap:

```
local_costmap:
  update_frequency: 3.0
  publish_frequency: 3.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 15
  height: 15
  resolution: 0.05
  origin_x: 0.0
  origin_y: 0.0
```

global_costmap:

```
global_costmap: 
  update_frequency: 2.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 40.0
  height: 40.0
  resolution: 0.05
```

Common_costmap:

```
footprint: [[-0.792, -0.344], [0.408, -0.344], [0.408, 0.344], [-0.792,0.344]]

observation_sources: scan scan2
scan: {sensor_frame: /laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
scan2: {sensor_frame: /laser2, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan2, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

I end in this situation because I notice my global plan didn't take in count the global costmap based on the map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233055/local-and-global-costmap-issues/) by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-04-28**:
what situation? it is not clear what is your problem.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-04-28**:
It's the same situation that this [one](http://answers.ros.org/question/54559/navfn-stability/)
I use 2 laserscans : one higher than the others.
I have correct the situation, I will post my config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Auto-answer time :) ... or at least better configs files without troubles :)

costmap_common:

```
footprint: [[-0.792, -0.344], [0.408, -0.344], [0.408, 0.344], [-0.792,0.344]]

observation_sources: scan scan2
scan: {sensor_frame: /laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
scan2: {sensor_frame: /laser2, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan2, marking: true, clearing: false}

inflation_radius: 0.344
```

global costmap:

```
#Independent settings for the planner's costmap
global_costmap: 
  update_frequency: 2.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: true
  rolling_window: map
  width: 40.0
  height: 40.0
  resolution: 0.05
```

local costmap:

```
local_costmap:
  update_frequency: 3.0
  publish_frequency: 3.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 5
  height: 5
  resolution: 0.1
  origin_x: 0.0
  origin_y: 0.0
```

Now the nav plan don't plan to go through map walls.

---

Originally posted by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) with karma: 109 on 2016-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0